# Access didn't add 1 record(s) to the table due to key violation. What is wrong here?

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys, key, composite-primary-key

I have the following structure: Timetable has COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY that consists of 2 FOREIGN KEYS - [*LECTURER'S ID*] and [*SUBJECT CODE*][[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWVO0.jpg)

When I'm trying to run the INSERT query INTO Timetable it gives me this error

[image]

But at the same time I can enter the values manually in [SUBJECT DETAILS] table without any problems!

[image]

How can I INSERT values INTO Timetable using query? Should I create Timetable in different way or something else?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: My guess is you're trying to insert `LECTURES_ID` or `SUBJECT_CODE` in `TIMETABLE` that are not present in `LECTURE'S_DETAIS` OR `SUBJECT_DETAILS` respectively.

Comment: no, as you can see I have records in [SUBJECT DETAILS] table, the same I have in [LECTURER'S DETAILS]

Comment: and I was trying to add the same values which exists in [LECTURER'S DETAILS] and [SUBJECT DETAILS]

Comment: May be you're right. Some of the records I can INSERT, some of them not, but both exists in the [LECTURER'S DETAILS] and [SUBJECT DETAILS] tables, I mean values [LECTURER'S ID] and [SUBJECT CODE].

Comment: what is the datatype of `DURATION`?

Comment: DURATION is INT

Comment: in `TIMETABLE`, if you've defined `LECTURE'S_ID` or `SUBJECT_CODE` as unique than the mentioned error will occur. Please verify this. If any of this 2 column defined as unique then kindly remove that constraint.

Comment: So as I understood FOREIGN KEY cannot be PRIMARY KEY as well, right?

Comment: Foreign key itself represents 1-to-many relationship. So, no a Foreign key should not be unique. But off course it can be used in a Composite Primary Key. So, in you case, in `TIMETABLE`, a particular `SUBJECT_CODE` or `LECTURE'S_ID` may appear in multiple rows, but a pair/combination of `(LECTURE'S_ID,SUBJECT_CODE` must be unique.

Comment: yes, that's the thing, this pair is unique, it determines DURATION.

Comment: Does being explicit help? `INSERT INTO TIMETABLE ([LECTURER'S ID], [SUBJECT CODE], [DURATION]) VALUES ('LID001', 'CE0014', 225)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem! Before writing queries I've created tables in Exel

[image]

And what I was doing, I was doing copy/paste values from Exel to my queries.
But when I tried to write values manually into the queries, it started to work!

I think when I was copying values from Exel, it was copying something else too, SO NEVER EVER COPY VALUES FROM EXEL TO YOUR QUERIES.

Comment: Awesome. Glad you found it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the names of the fields.

```
INSERT INTO TIMETABLE ([LECTURER'S ID], [SUBJECT CODE], [DURATION])
VALUES ('LID001', etc...
```

If you can, remove apostophes from field names and make all names one word, i.e., LecturersID, SubjectCode, etc.

Comment: Yeah, this might not help... if you can, supply a screenshot of the TIMETABLE indexes (add to the original question).

Comment: I removed apostroph, made all names of attributes one word, tried your example, problem remains the same. BTW I added screnshots of the TIMETABLE indexes, I tried to change them in different way, but doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately those aren't the indexes. Open table in design view and click the lightning bolt.